# thread communication, stop the work of a thread until data is entered PySide

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside

I've written a simple window with a start button that starts a Qthread. After a few instructions in the thread, I would like to display a SubWindow using Signal. Unfortunately, Qthread does not stop after displaying subWindow.

I'm looking for a solution like while Qthread is running: stop the Qthread, display a SubWindow, input the data, and send it directly to the Qthread, then start the thread.

One way I can think of is to open a window directly from the thread, but I don't think that's necessarily a good practice because I need to create a new instance of the app. In addition, there is still the problem of sending data from SubWindow to the thread

Problems:

- how to stop Qthread while displaying sub window
- how to pass data from sub window to Qthread

Code:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore
import sys, time

class InsertWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    signal_return_data = QtCore.Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("")
        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send")
        self.push.clicked.connect(self.send_it)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.push)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def send_it(self):
        if self.line.text() == '':
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            msg.setText("Not Empty")
            msg.show
        else:
            self.signal_return_data.emit(self.line.text())
            self.close()


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.txt = QtWidgets.QLabel("Welcome!")
        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.progres = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.push)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.progres)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.push.clicked.connect(self.p_start)

    def show_insert_popup(self):
        self.insert_win = InsertWindow()
        self.insert_win.signal_return_data.connect(self.send_to_thread)
        self.insert_win.exec_()

    def p_start(self):
        self.progres.setMinimum(0)
        self.progres.setMaximum(0)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.signal_open_insert.connect(self.show_insert_popup)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.stop_)
        self.worker.start()

    def stop_(self):
        self.progres.setMinimum(0)
        self.progres.setMaximum(100)


    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def send_to_thread(self, txt):
        self.txt.setText(f"{txt} Get It here, but need it in thread")


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    signal_open_insert = QtCore.Signal()
    def run(self):
        for x in range(2):
            print("I working in thread")
            time.sleep(2)
    
    # here I need stop thread (until the data will entered ), open subwindow, and get entered data to display
        self.signal_open_insert.emit()

        for x in range(2):
            print("Here i would like display dafa from insert window")
            time.sleep(1)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably just send it over a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), `queue.get()` is a blocking function so it will pause the thread execution until someone puts something in the queue.

just create a queue in the caller, let's call it `result_queue`, the child will call `result_queue.get()` on it to sleep and wait for an item to be put in it and the main thread will `put` the txt in it using `self.result_queue.put(txt)`.

just make sure you always `put` something in it even if an exception happens or the user cancels the operation otherwise the thread will hang forever, as i did by overriding the `reject` method of the dialog box.

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore
import sys, time
import queue
from typing import Optional

class InsertWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    signal_return_data = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("")
        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send")
        self.push.clicked.connect(self.send_it)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.push)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def reject(self) -> None:
        self.signal_return_data.emit('')
        super().reject()

    def send_it(self):
        if self.line.text() == '':
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            msg.setText("Not Empty")
            msg.show
        else:
            self.signal_return_data.emit(self.line.text())
            self.close()


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.txt = QtWidgets.QLabel("Welcome!")
        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.progres = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.push)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.progres)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.push.clicked.connect(self.p_start)
        self.result_queue: Optional[queue.Queue] = None

    def show_insert_popup(self):
        self.insert_win = InsertWindow()
        self.insert_win.signal_return_data.connect(self.send_to_thread)
        self.insert_win.exec_()

    def p_start(self):
        self.progres.setMinimum(0)
        self.progres.setMaximum(0)
        self.result_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.worker = Worker(self.result_queue)
        self.worker.signal_open_insert.connect(self.show_insert_popup)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.stop_)
        self.worker.start()

    def stop_(self):
        self.progres.setMinimum(0)
        self.progres.setMaximum(100)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def send_to_thread(self, txt):
        self.result_queue.put(txt)
        self.txt.setText(f"{txt} Get It here, but need it in thread")


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    signal_open_insert = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, results_queue: queue.Queue):
        self.results_queue = results_queue
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for x in range(2):
            print("I working in thread")
            time.sleep(2)

        # here I need stop thread (until the data will entered ), open subwindow, and get entered data to display
        self.signal_open_insert.emit()
        result = self.results_queue.get()

        for x in range(2):
            print("Here i would like display dafa from insert window")
            print(result)
            time.sleep(1)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain how it works?

Comment: @AnnAc0nda you just make a queue and put the text in it, the thread calling `results_queue.get()` will sleep until it gets the result from the other thread using `result_queue.put(txt)` ... you should probably read about [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), it 's a long but simple topic.

Comment: Hmm, if I woud like open window in loop until value will be correct? will it  work?

Comment: you can put the two lines of `self.signal_open_insert.emit();  result = self.results_queue.get()` in a loop and it will work, or you could modify `reject` to only call `super().reject()` and `put` data in the queue when the input is correct, you only have to make sure that something will be in the queue when the window is closed to not hang the thread forever, keep in mind that overriding the X button to prevent it from cancelling is bad user experience.

Comment: @AnnAc0nda doing some cleanup when the X button is pressed is acceptable, preventing the X button from cancelling is not an acceptable user experience.

Comment: can you tell me what doing this: `    def reject(self) -> None:
        self.signal_return_data.emit('')
        super().reject()` becouse if i use it. and try make loop, then it open SupWindow 2x and return two values, first wich i entred and second; " "

Comment: @AnnAc0nda it is intercepting the `X` button, to call the extra function first, before calling the real `reject` one in QT to remove the window, if this is removed your thread will get stuck when someone presses the `X` button, because it is waiting for the other signal to be emitted ... waiting forever.

Comment: So in this case it not working, becuse i emit signal with entred data `self.signal_return_data.emit(self.line.text())` and after i close window `self.close()` I think `self.close` work as `X`- Button and also directly emit another signal in `def reject()` (`self.signal_return_data.emit('')`), how else i can check if queue is empty?

Comment: @AnnAc0nda you have the `result` variable which can be anything, even a `None`, just pick something to signal an empty response and check for it `if result == user_entered_nothing: do_nothing()` ... the `do_nothing` should probably raise an error or return something to signal an error.

Comment: @AnnAc0nda also if you found this answer useful you should press on the "Correct mark" on the left of the answer to mark the question as answered, so others can benefit from it, you also get reputation to help you get answers on your questions.

Comment: @AnnAc0nda if you mean `stop` as in `pause` then there are [Lock Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) and [Condition Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) that all have their uses in pausing threads, but if you mean `stop` as in `terminate` then you can call `Worker.terminate()` but it is not recommended, and you should instead just `return` from inside the thread to end it.

Comment: Ii mean hold and send data to thread, in PySide itself, is this not implemented?

Comment: @AnnAc0nda if you want your application to not have many crashes you should probably stay away from QT when it comes to threads, and use python synchronization objects as pointed, you **MUST** avoid using threads with QT windows as it **WILL** crash you application, hope this is clear, keep all threading logic to python and away from QT, and only use signals for communication within QT, as QT windows are **NOT THREAD SAFE** and **WILL** lead to segmentation faults if modified from another thread, simply use python locks and queues and other python objects for communication between threads.